# What does `exit_status` mean in `kill -l [exit_status]`?

Tags: bash, kill

> ```
> kill [-s sigspec] [-n signum] [-sigspec] jobspec or pid
>
> kill -l [exit_status]
> ```
>
> Send a signal specified by sigspec or signum to the process named by
>   job specification jobspec or process id pid. sigspec is either a
>   case-insensitive signal name such as SIGINT (with or without the SIG
>   prefix) or a signal number; signum is a signal number. If sigspec and
>   signum are not present, SIGTERM is used. The -l option lists the
>   signal names. If any arguments are supplied when -l is given, the
>   names of the signals corresponding to the arguments are listed, and
>   the return status is zero. **`exit status` is a number specifying a signal
>   number or the exit status of a process terminated by a signal.** The
>   return status is zero if at least one signal was successfully sent, or
>   non-zero if an error occurs or an invalid option is encountered.

I was wondering what kind of value `exit_status` can take?

What does "`exit status` is a number specifying a signal number or the exit status of a process terminated by a signal" mean?

Comment: what o/s or linux flavor is this. on OS X, its pretty clear --                           -l [exit_status]
             If no operand is given, list the signal names; otherwise, write the signal name corresponding to exit_status.

Comment: Sorry. `kill` is a builtin in bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just exactly as the text says, you can supply one of two things:

- **a number specifying a signal number**: the signals are numbered 1, 2, 3, etc... (as you can see from the usage message for the common invocation). So you can ask `kill -l` to give you the name corresponding to such a number.
- **the exit status of a process terminated by a signal**: when processes are killed by a signal, they get a special exit status that is (usually? always?) 128 + the signal number that caused them to die. So you can ask `kill -l` to document that too.

Comment: Thanks. How can I use 'kill -l' to do the second thing instead of the first thing?

Comment: For example, `kill -l 139` displays `SEGV`, meaning that a process exiting with exit status 139 was terminated because it received signal SIGSEGV (11).

Comment: @Tim: you just give it an appropriate exit status.

Comment: Note that exit == 128 implies a core dump (minimum signal is 1, "kill 0" is a sanity check, not a signal).